# JSON.stringify(object) incorrect

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Sorry for my last question being so confusing, I was confused my self, but now I got a proper example:

```
var obj = {};
obj.entities = [];
obj.entities["player"] = [];
obj.entities["player"]["0"] = [];
obj.entities["player"]["0"]["pos"] = "0,0";

var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

// {"entities":[]}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

The output of `JSON.stringify(obj)` is wrong as you can see.
What causes this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're first building an array (`[]`), then assigning properties to it with non-number keys (`player`). This is technically possible (as in not causing an error), but it's not what arrays are for.

You should use objects (`{}`) instead. Also, `["player"]` is the same as `.player`.

```
var obj = {};
obj.entities = {};
obj.entities.player = []; // array here because you're filling with indices ([0])
obj.entities.player[0] = {}; // object again, because non-indices as keys (`pos`)
obj.entities.player[0].pos = "0,0";
```

Objects can take any property key. Arrays are a subset of objects, which should only have indices (numbers `>= 0`) as keys.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation, I wasn't fully aware of the object-array difference. But I could still do `obj.entities.player = {};` and then `obj.entities.player.pos = "0,0";` couldn't I ?

Comment: @elias94xx: If you have one player, then that would be possible. Though the `["0"]` you wrote makes me assume you have a list (array) of players somehow.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot about the id for a second. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your life would be much easier if you'd define your objects in JSON to begin with:

```
var obj = {
  'entities': [
    {'player':{'pos': '0,0'}}
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using named array indeces instead of object key/value pairs.

```
var obj = {};
obj.entities = {};
obj.entities["player"] = {};
obj.entities["player"]["0"] = [];
obj.entities["player"]["pos"] = "0,0";

// {"entities":{"player":{"0":[],"pos":"0,0"}}}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

`entities`, and `entities["player"]` and `entities["player"]["0"]` need to be **objects**, not arrays.

You're adding properties to these arrays, rather than pushing values onto them.  These custom properties are not getting stringified.

The fix is simple:

```
var obj = {};
obj.entities = {};   //  <------------ this is an object now
obj.entities["player"] = {};    // <--------- also an object
obj.entities["player"]["0"] = {};   // <-------- and so on
obj.entities["player"]["0"]["pos"] = "0,0";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some serious confusions about arrays and objects in javascript. An array (`[]`) works only with positive integer indexes. In your example you are doing the following:

```
obj.entities = [];
obj.entities["player"] = [];
```

You say that `obj.entities` is an array and then you use `player` as index. And `player` is not an integer. So this code makes no sense. On the other hand you could use objects with properties. Those properties can be strings:

```
obj.entities = {};
obj.entities.player = [];
obj.entities.player[0] = 'foo bar';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing objects with arrays. The following code will work.

```
var obj = {};
obj.entities = {};
obj.entities.player = [];
obj.entities.player[0] = {};
obj.entities.player[0].pos = "0,0";
```

The things you went wrong:

1. An array can have only integer indexes. So it's incorrect writing a["1"] *if you intend to use `a` as an array*.
2. To be correctly serialized, only an object can have named properties, like `object.entities.player` or `object.entities["player"]`.

Comment: Note that keys are always strings, so there is no difference between `["1"]` or `[1]`. The last is merely more semantical.